# My div content isn't loading from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to load my content of a `div` continuously from another page but it's not loading.

I have tried with `alert`, it worked fine but page data is not loading.

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function(){$("#loadAvailable").load("update.php");},1000);
    });
</script>
```

**update.php**

```php
<?php
include '../db.php';
echo "<ul>";
$sql = "SELECT cat, COUNT(*) as num_items, GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS accountID FROM accounts WHERE user = '0' GROUP BY cat";
if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<li><a href='#' draggable='false' id='".$row["cat"]."' onclick='Gen(this.id);'>".$row["cat"]." <span class='badge' id='".$row["cat"]."AV'>".$row["num_items"]."</span></a></li>";
        }
    }
}
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

**HTML code**

```html
<h3><b>Choose any option from below</b></h3>
    <div class="updateBox">
        <h4><div class="title">Available Items</div></h4>
        <div class="contents">
            <div id="loadAvailable">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$("#loadAvailable").load("update.php")` instead of `upload.php` you should pass an URL to your backend here, which will be routed to that php script

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: @AkibKhan can you console.log($("#loadAvailable")); is find or not ?

Comment: @AkibKhan, you are just doing one asynchronous task repeatedly. How do you stop it?

Comment: I want to show it repeatedly so it will update my div in every single changes without refreshing

Answer (score 1):

That should work, but you need to add some error checking as it may be the php page that is not working:

```
$( "#loadAvailable" ).load( "update.php", function( response, status, xhr ) {
  if ( status == "error" ) {
    alert(xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
  }
});
```